# What does the 'all' mean when defining custom css for a Django admin page

Tags: django, django-admin

The [django documentation indicates that custom css can be added to an Admin page as follows](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-media-definitions):

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        css = {
            "all": ("my_styles.css",)
        }
        js = ("my_code.js",)
```

It doesn't, however, explain what the "all" means in the css declaration.  What does it mean, and are there other values or configurations one could potentially use instead of "all"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`all` is for all types of media declarations which are:

> 'aural', 'braille', 'embossed', 'handheld', 'print', 'projection',
>   'screen', 'tty' and 'tv'

.

so, if you want a specific style for handheld:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        css = {
            "handheld": ("my_handheld_styles.css",)
            "all": ("my_styles.css",)
        }
        js = ("my_code.js",)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/forms/media/#css